# awk,sed help needed for addressing density

Tags: sed, awk, statistics

We are doing a study on livability and quality of life in high-density cities pulling information from sources that, when crunched, can provide an insight into the density ratio of apartments so as to hopefully determine “free space per human” and “concentration per human” in apartment complexes.

In the below example we are looking for the end result of enumerated apartment unit numbers for ONLY the units in parenthesis, all else can be ignored except zipcodes.

The word APT can be removed.
The left and right parenthesis can be removed.
The main address, for example, below, 7 Dense Road can be removed (we are not interested in precise address).
New York NY and zip code should remain as we are studying density by zipcode.

You will notice that there are some entries with just one apartment with no range - it would be good to keep that but not necessary as one unit apartments are generally penthouses or similar which have an abundance of space - we are interested in "how close people live next to one another, what configuration and how many neighbors they have".

So, for example, in the below submitted list of apartment ranges, the end result would be each unit number on its own line:

Our input text file looks like:

```
7 Dense Road  APT (Range 4A - 4D)
NEW YORK NY 10023-5040
7 Dense Road  APT (Range 5A - 5K)
NEW YORK NY 10023-5042
7 Dense Road  APT (Range 6A - 6E)
NEW YORK NY 10023-5043
7 Dense Road  APT 2A
NEW YORK NY 10023-5040
7 Dense Road  APT 2B
NEW YORK NY 10023-5040
7 Dense Road  APT 2C
NEW YORK NY 10023-5040
7 Dense Road  APT (Range 6F - 6J)
```

End result needed:

```
4A NEW YORK NY 10023-5040
4B NEW YORK NY 10023-5040
4C NEW YORK NY 10023-5040
4D NEW YORK NY 10023-5040
5A NEW YORK NY 10023-5042
5B NEW YORK NY 10023-5042
5C NEW YORK NY 10023-5042
5D NEW YORK NY 10023-5042
5E NEW YORK NY 10023-5042
5F NEW YORK NY 10023-5042
5J NEW YORK NY 10023-5042
5K NEW YORK NY 10023-5042
6A NEW YORK NY 10023-5043
6B NEW YORK NY 10023-5043
6C NEW YORK NY 10023-5043
6D NEW YORK NY 10023-5043
6E NEW YORK NY 10023-5043
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Duh. . . found an answer here.  My own question no less.  Go figure.

[awk, sed, or other text processing suggestions, please](https://superuser.com/questions/1389078/awk-sed-or-other-text-processing-suggestions-please)

The link referenced above is essentially the same format, albeit still needing to import each line via $1. I am hoping to somehow import via a file not $1.

```
#!/bin/bash

PART1=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/\(.*\)\s(.*/\1/')
PART3=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/.*)\(.*\)/\1/')
PART2=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/.*(\s*\(.*\)).*/\1/')

START=$(echo "$PART2" | sed 's/\s*-.*//')
END=$(echo "$PART2" | sed 's/.*-\s*//')

STARTNUM=$(echo "$START" | sed 's/^\(.\).*/\1/')
ENDNUM=$(echo "$END" | sed 's/^\(.\).*/\1/')
if test "$STARTNUM" '!=' "$ENDNUM"; then
    echo "Error: Numeral is different"
    exit 1
fi

STARTLETTER=$(echo "$START" | sed 's/^.\(.\).*/\1/')
ENDLETTER=$(echo "$END" | sed 's/^.\(.\).*/\1/')

OUTPUT=''
for LETTER in A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ; do
    test "$LETTER" '==' "$STARTLETTER" && OUTPUT='yes'
    test -n "$OUTPUT" && echo "$PART1, $STARTNUM$LETTER,$PART3"
    test "$LETTER" '==' "$ENDLETTER" && OUTPUT=''
done
```

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.